# Retrieving data all rows where specific user_id is present?

Tags: php, html, mysql, echo

I am working on a user profile page, and I have made it to where a user can post text and that will be uploaded to the "posts" database. That all works fine. But now I want to make it to where if a user goes to a users profile, it will echo out all their user posts. The database is laid out this way:

`post_id` `user_id` `content`

And I want to make it to where when a user lands on a user's page it grabs their $user_id and then forms a mysql_query and then echos out all of their posts that are present in the `users` database. What would be the best way to do this? Thanks

So far I have tried this:
`mysql_result("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = $user_id");`

Comment: very standard SELECT, what have you tried?

Comment: @Dagon I have done this: `mysql_result("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = $user_id");` but that doesn't work out. I think I need to use a "while" function. What do you think?

Comment: Is that the only way you select from database? if not post your whole code maybe it can help us think better.

Comment: you can't put the query under `mysql_result();`

Comment: see chintan's answer: you have to use `mysql_query` instead of `mysql_result`.   Also read up on parameterized queries, instead of building queries via string concatenation or inline variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing right thing.

You have to just fetch all the data using the while loop.

like.

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FORM posts WHERE user_id=$user_id");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{

echo $row['post_id'];
}
```

You got my point?

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. Alternatives to this function include: `mysqli_query();` or
`PDO::query();`

Comment: Ah, cool, yeah thats what I am aiming for, but is there a way to make it load only a certain amount of posts? And also a way to make a "Load More" button? Thanks.

Comment: SELECT * FROM city ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 15

Using this you can get only 0-15 result.

You can increase that limit on click on "Load More " button...

Comment: Okay, so would I want to use: `$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id=$user_id ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 0, 15");`

Answer (score 0):

```
 // execute the query
$stmt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id ='".$user_id."'");
```

then fetch using different php functions used to fetch data and display..

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($stmt)){
         echo $row['db_column_field'];
}
```